# Объясните смысл выражения в функции

Tags: javascript

Дана следующая функция:

```
function meanMode(numbers) {
  const result = numbers.reduce((count, number) => {
    count[number] = (count[number] || 0) + 1;
    return count;
  }, {});

  return result;
}
```

Она возвращает массив, в котором ключом является число, а значением - количество повторений в исходном массиве. Используется `Array.prototype.reduce()` .
Однако, я не понимаю данную строку: `count[number] = (count[number] || 0) + 1;`

А конкретно запись `(count[number] || 0)`. Что это значит?

Comment: Это предохранитель на случай, если ключа `number` ещё нет в `count` — в таком случае к единице прибавлялось бы `undefined` и получалось бы `NaN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(count[number] || 0)`

Вернуть `count[number]`, если его значение конвертируется в булевское `true`, в противном случае - вернуть `0`.